# if condition inside beanshell post processor is not working Jmeter

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, jmx

I am trying to set a flag inside beanshell post processor based on one if condition. Here always if condition becomes true. Please help to resolve this. I am unable to figure out what is the issue.

```
${__setProperty(access_tok,${access_tok},No)};
${__setProperty(token_typ,${token_typ},No)};

${__setProperty(flag,"false",No)};

if (${__property(token_typ)}.equals("bearer"))
{
${__setProperty(flag,"true",No)};
}
```

access_tok & token_typ are the regex variables. flag is user defined which I am trying to use it in further thread group's

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Beanshell, to for [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language
2. Don't inline [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into your scripts. As per [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation

   > When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.

Amended code should look like:

```
props.put('access_tok', vars.get('access_tok'))
props.put('token_typ', vars.get('token_typ'))

props.put('flag', 'false')

if (props.get('token_typ').equals('bearer')) {
    props.put('flag', 'true')
}
```

Comment: Do I need to replace Beanshell postprocessor to JSR223 ? Also I have used BeanShell for RegExtractor

Comment: JSR223 test elements with Groovy language performance is much better comparing to Beanshell. [Users are encouraged to switch to Groovy since JMeter 3.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Comment: Fine. Again same error. If condition is always executing.. Based on this flag I have a while condition & it always executes.

${__javaScript("${flag}".indexOf("true") == -1,)} while condition

Comment: Checked using debug post processor... It is always setting the value as true irrespective of that if condition

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve. In token generator if it fails for some reason i dont want to execute my second thread. Hence I am trying to set the flag value after if condition. 

But the if condition always executes and becomes true. Next i am executing while condition until the flag changes.

Please help me to achieve this. I am trying this approach for past 2 days but no luck

Comment: Found the issue. Once the flag value is set it is not resetting for each iteration.. First time if the value changes it is still using the old value. Can you please let me know how to reset the variable value for each iteration